# Gulp Fingerprinting + Production Deploys

Tags: javascript, deployment, gulp

I'm using gulp for common tasks on a front-end project.  My goal is to fingerprint my JS+CSS assets and update my `rev-manifest` on deploy without interrupting anything.  My tasks look something like this:

```
gulp.task("clean-js", function() {
   return del(["./public/shop-assets/javascripts/production/*.js", "./rev-manifest.json"], function(){
     console.log("Production JS folder and rev-manifest JSON cleared");
  });
});

gulp.task("clean-css", function() {
  return del(["./public/shop-assets/stylesheets/production/*.css", "./rev-manifest-css.json"], function(){
    console.log("Production CSS folder and rev-manifest-css JSON cleared");
  });
});

gulp.task('js:prod',['clean-js'], function() {
  return gulp.src("./public/shop-assets/javascripts/*.js/")
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/shop-assets/javascripts/production/"))
    .pipe(rev.manifest())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task('css:minify',["clean-css"], function() {
  return gulp.src("./public/shop-assets/stylesheets/*.css")
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/shop-assets/stylesheets/production/"))
    .pipe(rev.manifest())
    .pipe(rename("rev-manifest-css.json"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

This does what I expect-it clears the manifest files each time, then rewrites them.  What I would like to do is merely replace the contents of each manifest *after* I bundled + minified my JS +CSS files without blocking the user experience.

Also, in my express routes file, I am sending the manifest on down so I can then include the scripts/stylesheets like so:

```
script(src="/shop-assets/javascripts/production/#{assetPathJS}")
```

But when I delete and rewrite the manifest files, users will see an intermittent failure. 
Does anyone have any tips on this matter?  Most examples I have seen have only one entrypoint for the gulpfile.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing something like this in my routes files:

`var jsPaths = ServerConfig.assetPaths(["cleanout.js", "hiw.js", "do_good.js"], revManifestJS, "javascripts/");`

where that function assetPaths resolves the pathname based on the environment.  Simple than I thought.